# eloquent returning null value in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am doing a simple logic. I have 2 tables, attribute_type, and attribute_sub_type.
In AttributeSubType model, I have created this function.

```
 public function attribute_types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AttributeType');
}
```

And in AttributeType model, I have created this function.

```
public function attribute_sub_type()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AttributeSubType');
}
```

My View is:

```
@foreach($attributeSubTypes as $attributeSubType)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $attributeSubType->attribute_types['attribute_type'] !!</td> //this line returning null by dd($attributeSubType->attribute_types['attribute_type'])
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Where 'attribute_type' is a column in attribute_type table. I have used the same logic in another project. And that is working like charm.

Comment: Have you specify the name of the table under models. As the names should be plural. And even you can specify the foreign key in the related methods of the models

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Like replace the return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AttributeType'); with return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AttributeType', 'foreign_key', 'local_key); and do same in attribute_sub_type function.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by creating this method in the AttributeSubType model.

```
public function getAttributeType($id)
{
    $attribute = AttributeType::find($id);

    return $attribute->attribute_type;
}
```

And this is how I call it in View.

```
@foreach($attributeSubTypes as $attributeSubType)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $attributeSubType->getAttributeType($attributeSubType->attribute_type_id) !!}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: you can solve this better with relation, first be sure you have a attribute_type_id as foreign key in you attributesubtype model, you previous solution is correct but heck this criteria